# Strange output from FuseESB

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I am working on parsing the request.
I developed route in Java for parsing incoming request.

I am using Camel 2.9 with FuseESB 7.0.1.0.84.

I used `simple(“{body}”).getText()` to fetch incoming request as per Camel Manual

So I am checking the incoming request by using the code as:

```
if (xmlStringToParse == null || xmlStringToParse.equals("") || xmlStringToParse.equals("${body}")) {

            parsedXMLPath = "<error>Incoming request is as folows:"
                    + "\nValue of xmlStringToParse: " + xmlStringToParse
                    + "\n xmlStringToParse is empty: " + (xmlStringToParse.equals(""))
                   + "\n xmlStringToParse equals ${body}: " + (xmlStringToParse.equals("${body}"))
                    + "\nAgain checking incoming request:\n" + xmlStringToParse
                    + "</error>";
        }
```

Where `xmlStringToParse = simple(“${body}”).getText()`

The strange outcoming observed:

Value of `xmlStringToParse` is  changed in just one line from soap request to "". Also “`xmlStringToParse equals ${body}` “ is printed as “`xmlStringToParse equals`” without printing `${body}`. `${body}` is not printed in logs.

You can find the log output follows:

```
   <error>
    Value of xmlStringToParse: <somesoapRequest>
    xmlStringToParse is empty: false
   xmlStringToParse equals : true
  Again checking incoming request:
 </error>
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue and the reason for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used simple(“{body}”).getText() to fetch incoming request as per Camel Manual

Where did you see that? Do you have a link?

You should get the message body in another way than what you do, such as

```
String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```

Or if you use bean parameter binding, you can bind the message body and just declare the parameter to be of String type

```
public void foo(String body) {
   ...
}
```

See more details at the Camel docs such at: http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

Comment: ,I found the information on [http://camel.apache.org/simple.html](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) and [http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/BuilderSupport.html](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/BuilderSupport.html)

The problem here is that simple("${body}") gives right information in one instance and other instance in same time it modified by Fuse as "".
I am baffled by this strange behavior.

Comment: I also used `from(<someEndPoint>).streamCaching()` and `getContext().setStreamCache(true)` before posting this question.
But nothing helped.

Comment: As said you should get the message body as I instructed. You cannot do as you do. The simple is an org.apache.camel.Expression, which you would need to call the evaluate method, and pass in the Exchange which has the message header + payload etc. Read the links, and see the other examples to learn how to do this.

Comment: I did my previous coding using Exchange only.
Just was doing some R&D on simple where I noticed that strange behavior.